# How does the monkey utility work on Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, monkey

How does the monkey utility work on Android? Can we extend it somehow to send specific events instead of randomly generated ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want specific events, use the Monkey Runner tool: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Answer (score 3):

considering monkeyrunner being very unstable, you can directly trigger events using adb shell. 
e.g:
for triggering input

```
>>adb shell input
usage: input ...
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <key code number or name>
       input tap <x> <y>
       input swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
```

for installing use

```
adb install/uninstall <<apkname>>
```

for starting services and activities:

```
adb shell am startservice -a <<service name>>
```

To start an activity:

```
adb shell am start -n <<activity name>>
```

adb is more reliable since you get the feedback immediately unlike monkeyrunner which does not provide reliable exceptions in case of any failure in triggering the event.

Another alternative is to use a monkey script:

We can supply a script to the monkey tool using the -f option. for e.g:
monkey -f <>

e.g monkey script
https://gist.github.com/3796686

**Some additional info:**
MonkeyRunner internally uses monkey to trigger event. Monkey runs inside the emulator listening on a port and monkeyrunner opens a socket to that port and passes the command to monkey which in turn executes it.